# Different zsh terminal prompt when outside git directory

Tags: git, terminal, zsh

Does anyone know how to do this? I need/want my right prompt to display time when I'm outside a git directory, and I want it to show the branch when I'm inside a git dir.

This is the config I use, [extracted from git doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Zsh):

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
precmd_vcs_info() { vcs_info }
precmd_functions+=( precmd_vcs_info )
setopt prompt_subst
RPROMPT=\$vcs_info_msg_0_
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b'
```

But want to use `RPROMPT="%*"` when outside git dir.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put everything into your own precmd function.  Here's an example (add this to `~/.zshrc`):

```
my_precmd() {
  vcs_info
  psvar[1]=$vcs_info_msg_0_
  if [[ -z ${psvar[1]} ]]; then
    psvar[1]=${(%):-%*}
  fi
}

autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b'
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd my_precmd
RPROMPT=%1v
```

Some notes:

- `vcs_info` Calls the zsh builtin to set `$vcs_info_msg_0_`.
- `zstyle ...` Configures the result from `vcs_info`.
- `psvar[1]` The `psvar` array is a set of special variables that can be referenced easily in a prompt (`%1v`).
- `if [[ -z ${psvar[1]} ]]` Tests to see if anything was set by `vcs_info`; if the result is zero-length, use the time instead.
- `${(%):-%*}` Gets the time. There are a few pieces: `(%)` says to substitute percent escapes like in a prompt, `:-` is used to create an anonymous variable for the substitution, and `%*` is the prompt escape that sets the time.
- `add-zsh-hook ...` Adds `my_precmd` to the precmd hook, so it'll be called prior to each prompt. This is preferable to setting `precmd_functions` directly.
- `RPROMPT=%1v` Sets the right-side prompt to always display the value of `psvar[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. But it didn't work :(

Comment: I should have asked you to clarify 'git directory'.  Please try the updated version; it now uses the variable set by `vcs_info` to determine which prompt to use.

Comment: @FrVentura - do you have any more info beyond "it didn't work"? With more details, we may be able to determine why this works on my system but not yours.