# How can I modify my zsh terminal prompt to show the current working directory and current git branch (if applicable)?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I am running macOS Big Sur v11.2. I would like my zsh terminal prompt to look like this:

`/directoryName/ (gitbranch) $`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is use a zsh `precmd` to build the prompt with the `vcs_info` builtin.  Try adding this to `~/.zshrc` and restarting the terminal session:

```
my_precmd() {
  vcs_info
  psvar[1]=$vcs_info_msg_0_
  if [[ -n ${psvar[1]} ]]; then
    psvar[1]=" (${psvar[1]})"
  fi
}

autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b'
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd my_precmd
PROMPT='%d/%1v $ '
```

Some notes about the pieces are here:
[Different zsh terminal prompt when outside git directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64093788/different-zsh-terminal-prompt-when-outside-git-directory/64094551#64094551)

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to show the current directory I'm in without the full path so I changed ````%d/%1v```` to ````/%./%1v````