# Remove `git:(master)` from oh my zsh terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I get `git:(master)` on every directory in the terminal ( There is no `.git` directory ).

How to remove that and only show git info if there is a git repo.
This is how it looks right now:

[image]

I am using oh my zsh with the default theme.

I have tried to reinstall iterm2 and oh my zsh but the same issue.

Here is my `echo $PS1` result:

`%(?:%{%}➜ :%{%}➜ ) %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)`

Thanks!

Comment: These answers that show how to do it without oh-my-zsh might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66104574/9307265 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64094551/9307265 . Not sure how to make it work with omz.